# AngularJS / Strange behavior while validating email uniqueness

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

I have a form controlled by Angular, and I expect this to be aware of potential duplicated user's email.

My concerned code is there: http://plnkr.co/edit/XQeFHJTsgZONbsrxnvcI

It contains both directives:

- `ngFocus`: to be able to have the information whether any inputs is on focus or blur.
            It also takes care about a `hasVisited` variable in order to avoid to validate      the input on `blur` if it hasn't been reached at least once by the user.
- `emailUnique`: executing a simple comparison with the mail already existing (hard-coded), in order to be able to validate or not the `email` input.

The point is: (don't forget to put "tab" touch to get `blur` function executed in order to see the field's validation error)

- If I enter nothing and go to the Name input (to blur the email input), it displays: **The field is required**. That's good.
- If I enter a non-valid email like the string "ferfergre", it displays: **This email isn't valid.**. That's good.
- If then I enter a valid e-mail different from the already existing hardcoded one: (michael@gmail.com), no error is displayed. That's good.
- If I enter the existing mail: michael@gmail.com, it displays: **This email already exists.**. That's good since it warns about it.
- However, if at least once during the DOM cycle, an e-mail was judged "This email already exists", then even if I change it to a new valid one, this error stays...

**Question: How to deal with the last case ?**

I have two assumptions:

- Order of HTML attributes would matter: `autofocus email-unique ng-focus required`
- `setValidity` method in `emailUnique` directive code avoids `ctrl` to be `$valid` again, and then prevents the mail comparison to be executed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this snippet from your parser function:

```
if(!ctrl.$valid){
    return viewValue;
}
```

This code was preventing the mail comparison to be executed again.

With this snippet there, the code below it (which does the comparison) will only run if the control is valid, but will never run if the control is invalid.

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6q3cANiFI4vpWcVEHRvo?p=preview

---

#### Edit (better alternative):

If you don't want to perform the comparison when the email field is not valid for **the other rules** ("required" and "email"), then you will need to check also for `ctrl.$error`. Instead of removing the snippet mentioned above, just change it to:

```
if(!ctrl.$valid && !ctrl.$error.emailUnique){
    return viewValue;
}
```

This way, it will only return if the control is invalid but due to **other** rule (not the emailUnique one).

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IDQitVkeHHDyJlcsatMy?p=preview

Comment: Far more efficient the alternative. Thanks :)